# Where can I find tutorial files of Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have installed postgresql on my ubuntu machine using,

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

Now I am reading [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-sql-intro.html) however could not figure out where the tutorial files (e.g., basics.sql) are.

Where can I find or download them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're in the PostgreSQL source distribution:

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/tutorial

Aside: the latest PostgreSQL is 9.3, not 9.1:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-sql-intro.html

Comment: I tried `apt get install postgresql-9.3` but didn't work. Do I need to clone this github repo first and then `make` it on my machine? (I use ubuntu)

Comment: Clone it for the tutorial filesnly. To install 9.3: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: You need to follow these [steps](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/37992-missing-basics-sql-and-other-postgresql-tutorials)